# Rails validate params in pundit policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, drag-and-drop, authorization, pundit

I am creating a trello style app where a user can drag cards between lists. I am handling all the reordering logic on the js side, and am posting the `list_id` and `position` to the rails update action in my controller:

```
card = authorize Card.find(params[:id])
card.update(card_params)
```

The authorize method, provided by pundit, looks like this:

```
def update?
  user.can_edit?(card.board)
end
```

This is only checking the if the user is authorized to edit the board. Because I am permitting the `list_id` attribute, a user could very well make a POST to move a card to a list which he does not have access to. To solve this, I added this condition to my controller:

```
if current_user.can_edit? List.find(params[:list_id]).board
  // update card
else 
  // handle error
end
```

This solution does the job, but I don't want to introduce any authorization into my controller. My pundit policy does not have access to the `card_params`, and the model does not have access to the devise `current_user`, so this seems like the only way. Is there a way I could stick this logic into the policy?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, I just had to authorize the new list through the list policy:

```
authorize List.find(params[:list_id])
```